# Is it possible to call scope in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to use this scope in controller.
How can I add to this line? 
I couldn't just put `.recent` anywhere in the line....
Now I can ignore `order: 'updated_at DESC'`
I just left that just in case.

**User controller**

```
@users = User.find_by_username(params[:id]).all_following(order: 'updated_at DESC')
```

**User model**

```
scope :recent, lambda { |n = 10| order("last_active_at DESC").limit(n) }
```

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Charles Thanks for a comment. `recent` scope constrain User records into the 10 latest Users. I'd like to fetch 10 users whom I'm following. and It has to be ordered by the column called `last_active_at`

Answer (score 2):

Just write

```
@users = User.find_by_username(params[:id]).all_following.recent
```

in your controller. This should give you the recent users you're following. The beauty of scopes is that you can concatenate them (in this case `all_following` and `recent`).

By the way, I doubt that finding a username with an id makes sense. You will either need to say `User.find(params[:id]).all_following.recent` or `User.find_by_username(params[:username]).all_following.recent`, in case you have the user name in the params hash.

Comment: It gives back `undefined method `recent'` This have to be fine since I'm using this method in the other action